# Angular 4.3 Interceptors - How to use?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I am in the process of building a new app that requires authorization headers. Typically I use something very similar to the approach found in this [scotch.io article](https://scotch.io/@kashyapmukkamala/using-http-interceptor-with-angular2). But it has come to my attention that HTTP Interceptors are now fully supported within the Angular 4 ecosystem via the new HttpClientModule and I am trying to find some documentation on how exactly to use them.

If I am incorrect in (as of 4.3) this being the best practice for injecting authorization headers, I'd also be open to suggestions. My thinking was that it was a feature added recently which means there is probably good reason to migrate to an "Angular Approved" method.

Comment: http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2017/07/17/http-client-module/  this seems useful

Comment: You can check https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/tree/v1.0 1.x branch as the example.

Comment: The official angular documentation is pretty good: https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-new-headers

Comment: @CodeWarrior How did I miss that? Must be a new section? I even tried to find it before tapping out this question. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer is borrowing from the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-new-headers) linked to by CodeWarrior.

Angular allows you to create an HttpInterceptor:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

which you can then integrate into your app like so:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: NoopInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  }],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

To add an authorization header, you can clone the request with the changed headers:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Get the auth header from the service.
    const authHeader = this.auth.getAuthorizationHeader();
    // Clone the request to add the new header.
    const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authHeader)});
    // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Note that the interceptors act like a chain, so you can set up multiple interceptors to perform different tasks.

Comment: why is the clone for? why not just set the headers directly in the `req` with `rew.headers.set` ?

Comment: Dag, according to the documentation, the headers object is immutable, so if you want to make changes to it, you have to clone it.

Comment: is it the same in angular 4.2.3 ?

Comment: @bharathmuppa The 4.3.2 (I'm assuming this is what you meant) documentation is unchanged from the examples above.

Comment: @john I am referring to 4.2.x, because when I am using interceptor js interpreter executing till interceptor function while loading, but when i call the http service interceptor function is not being executed.

Comment: @bharathmuppa I couldn't find specific documentation, so I asked on their Gitter channel and I've received confirmation that it's 4.3 upwards.

Comment: @john angular cli is coming with 4.2.x so can i move to 4.3 or 4.4 as it is still RC?

Answer (score 3):

Injecting AuthService to the Interceptor's constructor was giving me this error:

> Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic
>   dependency! InjectionToken_HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ("[ERROR ->]"): in
>   NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1

So instead of injecting it to the constructor, I used `Injector` of `@angular/core` and it worked fine. I am storing the token in `localStorage` and using basic auth. I need to set

```
Authorization: 'Bearer token_string'
```

**Here is how I have implemented:**

***token.interceptor.ts***

```
import {Injectable, Injector} from '@angular/core';

import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        const auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
        if (auth.getToken()) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.getToken()}`
                }
            });

        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

***getToken function in AuthService***

Here you can implement the whole logic to get the header or only the token. Here in my case, I am only calling this to get the JWT token string.

```
/**
 * Get jwt token
 * @returns {string}
 */
getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
```

***app.module.ts***

Import the `TokenInterceptor`

```
import {TokenInterceptor} from './pathToTheFile/token.interceptor';
```

add the following under `@NgModule` in `providers:` array.

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: TokenInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }
    //, other providers
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had with the recommended approach, was that the interceptors had to be known at compile time and, apparently, all in the same module.

I opted for implementing one interceptor and a chain of handler functions which can be extended at runtime. The service's intercept method takes care of the next() logic.

The service (basic code, no validations or maintenance):

```
export type HttpHandlerFunction = (req: HttpRequest<any>) => HttpRequest<any>;

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    private _handlers: Array<HttpHandlerFunction> = [];

    addHandler(handler: HttpHandlerFunction): void {
        this._handlers.push(handler);
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
        Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            this._handlers.forEach((handler: HttpHandlerFunction) => {
                req = handler(req);
            })
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

And the usage, in some service in a different module:

```
constructor(injector: Injector) {

    const interceptorsArray: Array<any> = injector.get(HTTP_INTERCEPTORS),
        interceptor: HttpInterceptorService = interceptorsArray &&
            interceptorsArray.filter((i: any) => i instanceof HttpInterceptorService)[0];
    if (interceptor) {
        interceptor.addHandler((req: HttpRequest<any>) => {
            const accessToken = this.getAccessToken();
            if (accessToken) {
                // doesn't work with direct headers.set, you must clone
                req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', accessToken) });
            }
        return req;
    });
}
```